# handle connection iphone vs proxy

Tags: iphone, proxy

I use my http proxy(squid) over 3G network.

**Apn:xxxxx

username:xxxx

password:xxxx

proxy=x.x.x.x**

In 3g it isn't  possible to add username/password in the proxy configuration.I want that my proxy should know the http request source(sent by how). Is it possible to add some value in all header requests sent by the iphone and to handle connections between the iphone and the proxy from my iphone apps ?

Answer (score 0):

i found this profil configuration to redirect all traffic and to send usrname/psswd to a proxy over 3g.
is this right ?

`<key>`apn`</key>`
`<string>`mobile.test.com`</string>`
`<key>`proxy`</key>`
`<string>`proxy.test.corp.local`</string>`
`<key>`proxyPort`</key>`
`<integer>`8080`</integer>`
`<key>`proxyUsername`</key>`
`<string>`test\myname`</string>`
`<key>`proxyPassword`</key>`
`<string>`mypassword`</string>`

Comment: Have you found anything new here? I would be really interested!

Comment: NO; just I used multiple ports to differentiate between user.
there is no solutions, thx Apple